# Making Navbar Transparent Bootstrap and Leftover chunks of color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly: I've been trying to make the navbar transparent, looked up how to here, but the solutions haven't quite worked (or at least not as I expected). I'm using bootstrap, this is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I added in this custom CSS to change the navbar to transparent:

```
.navbar-inner {
background: transparent;
background-color: transparent;
border-width: 0px;
```

}

The CSS loads properly, but nothing changes in the navbar (at least I assumed it would be white, since the browser background is?)

I tried changing the background-color in the above CSS, and it did change it, but I got this result:

[image]

I'm wondering, even if I do get it transparent, how do I get rid of that bottom border (thought I set border-width to 0px already), and what are those black chunks on the side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.navbar` class insted of `.navbar-inner`, because Bootstrap has background on `.navbar` element.

```
.navbar {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `opacity: 0.5;` in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

you should try out the new css3 transparent feature "rgba" - the a stands for alpha channel

http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html